# Understanding Newton's third law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, biology

So recently I learned about Newton's third law. My professor told that if I go to a fight with a sumo wrestler and sumo wrestler punches me with a force of 5000N in my stomach , My stomach also pushes him with a force of 5000N. Even though force on my stomach and that on wrestler's hand have same magnitude , this force will have different impact on both. It will create more pain to my stomach than to wrestler's  hand, it will create more deformation to my stomach than to wrestler's hand, it will create more motion in me than in wrestler, all because I have less inertia as compared to wrestler's.

My doubt is

1. The force would create same pain in both: my stomach and wrestler's hand but my stomach will not be able to bear that pain but wrestler will be. So how more pain to my stomach?
2. It will create more deformation in my stomach than to wrestler's hand because of more elasticity of my stomach, what's that to do with our inertia?

I understood that motion created in us would be different due to our different masses.

Can anyone tell where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: You are equating equal magnitudes of force, in opposite directions, with equal pain felt by each person, which is purely a subjective experience.  However, what does that have to do with Newton's third law?  Do you believe Newton's third law or not?

Comment: everyone here believes in newton's third law

Comment: I'm not questioning validity of newton's third law but what confuses me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Surely your stomach will feel more pain.  It's a very sensitive area.  Lots of muscle and organs, not too much bone.  Your hand ... boney.  I volunteer to try it with you.  Would you rather I punch you in the stomach, or you punch me?
2. Inertia can be quantified. The quantity of inertia is *mass*.   I'm guessing here that your professor is thinking about conservation of momentum.  Newton's third law implies that the momentum change of the two objects is equal and opposite.  Their magnitudes are the same.  So for a given change of momentum, the lighter weight object has to move faster than the heavier object in order to compensate for the respective masses.

Comment: why same force producing more pain

Comment: Pain has little to do with physics.  Pain is about physiology and the brain.